# Running an exe from an ant build script problems

Tags: ant, exec, executable, target

I'm trying to run an executable from an ant build script and having no joy. The executable runs but hangs. Basically this program takes a file in and converts it to another format and splits it into parts a bit like zip utility.

I call it from a command line with the call:-

```
BCC FILE.NAME -d FOLDER
```

whereby

- `BCC` is the call to the executable
- `FILE.NAME` is the file to be converted
- `-d` is parameter to put output files in specific location
- `FOLDER` is the output folder for the files

So in the ant script I am using the exec executable command and passing FILE.NAME,-d and FOLDER as three separate arguments to no avail